# android handler wait/sleep not working

Tags: android, delay, handler, android-handler

I'm having trouble implementing a handler for a delay function. This is supposed to be a simple dice game.

When it is the computer's turn to roll the dice, there is supposed to be a pause in between each roll so the user can see what the computer rolled. When I run the code, it should wait for 2 sec before rolling again. This does not happen.

This is my first post on stackoverflow. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 2000);  //delay run for 2 seconds
  }
};

public void computerTurn() {
  rollButton.setEnabled(false);   //disable UI for cpu's turn
  holdButton.setEnabled(false);
  ImageView diceImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dicePic);
  Random r = new Random();

  diceRoll = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
  switch (diceRoll) {
    case 1:
      compTurnScore = 0;
      diceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice1);
      compTurnScoreTxt.setText("Computer Turn Total :" + compTurnScore);
      break;
    case 2: ...
    case 3: ...
    case 4: ...
    case 5: ...
    case 6:
      compTurnScore += 6;
      diceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice6);
      compTurnScoreTxt.setText("Computer Turn Total :" + compTurnScore);
      break;
  }

  timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);   //run the timerhandler without any delay
  if(compTurnScore < 20)    //if cpu rolls less than 20 keep rolling
    computerTurn();
}
```

Comment: Try `Thread.sleep(2000)`

Comment: Inside `timerRunnable`, remove `timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 2000);  //delay run for 2 seconds` and put `if(compTurnScore < 20)    //if cpu rolls less than 20 keep rolling
        computerTurn();` And call `timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 2000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I get it correct you want `computerTurn()` to executed so, that if dice rolling happens it should be shown with dealy only if another `computerTurn()` needs to be called (condition of `compTurnScore < 20`).

If you want to use `Handler`s I would propose to look at it as "lets call `computerTurn()` in a delayed fashion from `Handler`". Code would be something like this (based on your original code):

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler(); // Created in Main thread thus handled in Main thread
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    computerTurn(); // Called in Main thread
  }
};

public void computerTurn() {
  rollButton.setEnabled(false);   //disable UI for cpu's turn
  holdButton.setEnabled(false);
  ImageView diceImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dicePic);
  Random r = new Random();

  diceRoll = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
  switch (diceRoll) {
    case 1:
      compTurnScore = 0;
      diceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice1);
      compTurnScoreTxt.setText("Computer Turn Total :" + compTurnScore);
      break;
    case 2: ...
    case 3: ...
    case 4: ...
    case 5: ...
    case 6:
      compTurnScore += 6;
      diceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice6);
      compTurnScoreTxt.setText("Computer Turn Total :" + compTurnScore);
      break;
  }

  if(compTurnScore < 20) {   //if cpu rolls less than 20 keep rolling
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 2000);   //request another round of computerTurn() to be called after 2 sec
  }
}
```

Please note that some leaking might be in order here for `computerTurn()` can be called at the time when `Activity` or `Fragment` context might not be present anymore. Follow other posts on how to check if `Activity` or `Fragment` is still in state so that you can safely access it's views.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That worked exactly as I wanted.